# Do I need a transit visa for the connecting flight in Kuwait?

Tags: transit, india, greece, kuwait

I'm travelling from Hyderabad, India, to Athens, Greece, which I have a connecting flight through Kuwait. From India to Kuwait I have booked Indigo Airlines and the connecting flight from Kuwait to Greece I have Flight Kuwait airways.

Do I need any transit visa to pass through the connecting flight?

Comment: Yes, if this are two separate bookings (likely) and also yes for single booking the layover is more than 4 hours.

Comment: yes it's a single booking with different airlines and a layover is 10 hours in kuwait, inthese case also we need transit visa ??

Comment: but currently transit visa isn't available

Comment: @MANIKYAMMAHI It might be a single booking, but it's definitely not a single ticket in the connection sense

Answer (score 3):

You will need a visa, as this is two tickets stitched into a single one, since Indigo only partners with Turkish Airlines on this route (confirmed on their flight booking page)

---

Assuming you're an Indian national, my best guess about how you can obtain a visa is to contact any agency recognized by the Kuwait Consulate in Mumbai (the only one in the country) and inquire with them

The list is available on the consulate's [site](https://www.kuwaitconsulate.in/agents.html)

If you are a national of any country mentioned on the [e-visa page](https://evisa.moi.gov.kw/evisa/home_e.do), you can apply directly on there