# Kuwait transit visa requirements for Nepalese travelling to Nepal, living in the UK

Tags: transit-visas, uk-residents, kuwait, nepali-citizens

I am travelling to Nepal from the UK and have a layover of more than 10 hours at Kuwait airport. UK-Kuwait & Kuwait-Nepal are with different airlines, same for the return flights.

Do I need to apply for a transit visa for self transfer? Can I apply at the airport like some countries provide such as Malaysia?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do I need a transit visa for the connecting flight in Kuwait?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/182579/do-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-the-connecting-flight-in-kuwait)

Comment: For completeness, are you resident in the UK?

Comment: Yes a resident, living on a spouse visa for last 5 years.